# Align dynamic Image and Text in Android

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I have a header where I have the text: "Huidige Locatie" and beneath that I have an image of a country flag.

I declared the TextView and ImageView in the layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locatiebalk"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vlaggenlocatie"
                android:layout_width="105sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="14sp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/huidiglocatie"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Huidige locatie"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/flag"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="46sp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/nl"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

(I close the tags correctly later on, just showing the relevant part)

In the Graphical Layout of Eclipse it shows it the right way:

[image]

But in the Simulator and on my phone it showes it like this:
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

For the ones wondering: `android:scaleType="fitStart"` did the job.